# Can't get image file name from POST object

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the name of img file from html form, but browser shows me the following error:
Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\login tutorial\index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\login tutorial\index.php on line 12

Here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstName = $_POST['fname'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $firstName = $_POST['fname'];
        $passwordConfirm = $_POST['confPassword'];

        $imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

        echo $firstName . "<br>" . $lastName . "<br>" . $email . "<br>" . $password . "<br>"
        . $passwordConfirm . "<br>" . $imageName . "<br>" . $imageSize;
    }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data ">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
                <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
                <label for="password">Password</label><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
                <label for="confPassword">Confirm Password</label><br>
                <input type="password" name="confPassword" id="confPassword"><br>
                <input type="file" name="image"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
```

UPDATE: It looks like I did't get the image file... Any reason for that?

Comment: follow this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use html attribute form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Example: `<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Did that. Still doesn't work.